# Trouble compiling code with TransparentBlt()

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I was having a lot of trouble with compiling a simple program containing the TransparentBlt() function (defined in wingdi.h). Before linking msimg32.lib to my project I was getting errors that were mostly undefined references to several wingdi.h functions, but after I linked it the only error left was with TransparentBlt():

> [Linker error] undefined reference to `TransparentBlt@44'
>
> ld returned 1 exit status
>
> C:\Dev-Cpp\Makefile.win [Build Error]  [pt.exe] Error 1

Here is the code:

```
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    HDC hdc=GetDC(HWND_DESKTOP); HDC MemDC=CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
    SelectObject(MemDC,(HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL,(LPCTSTR)"F:\\output.bmp",IMAGE_BITMAP,1366,768,LR_LOADFROMFILE));
    TransparentBlt(hdc,683,384,683,384,MemDC,0,0,683,384,RGB(0,0,255));
}
```

I've been searching for days on Google, but no one who linked msimg32.lib to his project had this error. Is there something else I could be doing wrong?

Comment: http://www.cemetech.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1560&start=0